# Assign random values to column according to another column's values in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has Stock Codes with the range from 2-90214 (which has around 3000 unique values). Obviously, some values between 2 and 90214 are getting skipped. I want to convert these stock codes so that they range from 1-3000 and in such a way that if the previous stock code was 1234, then everytime this number occurs, the new stock code (say 100) will be assigned.

In short, I want to convert :

```
Stock_Code
 1234
 5678
 4321
 1234
 5678
```

into :

```
Stock_Code
 100
 101
 102
 100
 101
```

How do I do this in R ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert the numbers into factor and then transform it into numeric

```
as.numeric(factor(df$StockCode))

#[1] 1 3 2 1 3
```

If we need it starting from 100 we can add 99 in it

```
as.numeric(factor(df$StockCode)) + 99
```

Same numbers would get same factor level which upon converting into numeric would give same numeric value

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match` to get the index of the unique values, and then add 99

```
df1$Stock_Code <- match(df1$Stock_Code, unique(df1$Stock_Code)) + 99
df1$Stock_Code
[1] 100 101 102 100 101
```

---

Or another option is to convert to `factor` and coerce to `integer`

```
with(df1, as.integer(factor(Stock_Code, levels = unique(Stock_Code)))+ 99)
#[1] 100 101 102 100 101
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dense_rank(df$Stock_Code) + 99
```

Comment: This doesn't give the expected output.  If you have checked it

Comment: Yes i know, but it addresses ' I want to convert these stock codes so that they range from 1-3000 and in such a way that if the previous stock code was 1234, then everytime this number occurs, the new stock code (say 100) will be assigned.' that OP wanted, i guess he just provided an example for understanding. OP can verify what he exactly wanted.