# Avoid: Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r

I have used the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information) to convert my factors to numeric, but get the following warning message. How can this be overcome?

```
typ_A <- c("2S", "3C", "3H", "4P", "4S", "5H", "CV", 
              "EX", "MV", "PU", "SW", "TR", "UV", "VN",
              "2C", "2S", "3C", "3H", "4P", "4S", "5H", "CV", 
              "EX", "MV", "PU", "SW", "TR", "UV")
typ_B <- c(1:28)

df1 <- data.frame(typ_A, typ_B)
df1$typ_A2 <- as.numeric(levels(df1$typ_A))[df1$typ_A]
```

Comment: How do you expect `"2S"` or `"3C"` to be numeric ?

Comment: to take the numeric 1, it is the first factor to appear

Comment: so we obtain 1:`length(unique(typ_A))` factors

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734401/assign-random-values-to-column-according-to-another-columns-values-in-r) ?

Comment: great, that was exactly it. link it below and I will close the question